# Why doesn't `appendChild` work as expected when passed an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass an anonymous function to the `appendchild` function.

I'm getting the following error message though:

> Uncaught TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 does not implement interface Node.

Seems as if the anonymous function isn't returning the required type? In comparison, if I define a named function with the same code in it and pass that to the `appendChild` function I'm not getting an error.

See the following code for clarification:

```js
// Option 1
function appendThis() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  parent.appendChild(function () {
    var child = document.createElement("div");
    child.classList.add("child");
    child.classList.add("red");
    child.innerHTML = "appendThis()";
    return child;
  });
}

// Option 2
function appendThat() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  var child = document.createElement("div");
  child.classList.add("child");
  child.classList.add("green");
  child.innerHTML = "appendThat()";
  parent.appendChild(child);
}

// Option 3
function createChild() {
  var child = document.createElement("div");
  child.classList.add("child");
  child.classList.add("yellow");
  child.innerHTML = "createChild()/appendThese()";
  return child;
}
function appendThese() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  parent.appendChild(createChild());
}
```

```css
main{
  height: 98vh;
  width: 98vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
button{
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
hr{
  width: 200px;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.child{
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="parent"></div>
        <hr>
        <button class="red" onclick="appendThis();">AppendThis</button>
        <button class="green" onclick="appendThat();">AppendThat</button>
        <button class="yellow" onclick="appendThese();">AppendThese</button>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: `appendChild` appends document object model (DOM) nodes, not functions. You are confusing a function with a value returned by a function call. An expression like `function() { }` is not *calling* the function, it evaluates to the function itself.

Comment: You did not _execute_ your function. This would need to be `parent.appendChild(function () { ...}());` to work - note the extra set of `()`

Comment: *"im trying to pass an anonymous function to the appendchild()-function"* That's the problem. `appendChild` accepts **nodes** (and fragments), not functions. What are you trying to do by passing it a function? Did you mean to call the function? (If so, why define it inline?)

Comment: amn, CBroe, T.J Crowder thanks for your comments. I mistakenly expected the function to be executed when it is passed as argument. All your comments helped me. @CBroe, since your comment is solving my issue, would you mind posting it as answer so i can mark the question as answered? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parent.appendChild(function () {
  var child = document.createElement("div");
  child.classList.add("child");
  child.classList.add("red");
  child.innerHTML = "appendThis()";
  return child;
});
```

You did not actually *execute* your function there.

You need to add `()` after the function definition, if you want to execute it at this point.

This is what's called an IIFE - Immediately-Invoked Function Expression. More details on that can be found here: [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)